# hadoop 50070 Datanode tab won't show both data nodes

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I know it is a duplicate question but since the other questions did not have answers with it, I am reposting it. I have recently installed hadoop cluster using 2 VMs on my laptop. I could go and checkout port 50070 and under datanodes tab I can see only one data node, but I have 2 data nodes, one on master node and other on slave node. What could be the reasons?

Comment: Can you please see if datanode processes are running on both the VMs

Comment: yes they are running on both nodes when I see using JPS

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, feels like it's been a time. But still I'd like to share my answer: the root cause is from hadoop/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml: the xml file has a property named dfs.datanode.data.dir. If you set all the datanodes with the same name, then hadoop is assuming the cluster has only one datanode. So the proper way of doing it is naming every datanode with a unique name:

[image]
Regards, YUN HANXUAN